# Angular $http service, Steam DotA 2 API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http, get

I just started out with AngularJS, and I have a question regarding $http service and receiving data from web server, I made this simple script that was supposed to get JSON from Steam's DotA2 API but for some reason it's not getting data, here are index.html and script.js respectively:

```
<html ng-app="steamPowered">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>
        Angular
    </title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <div>
        <p>{{errx}}</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Player ID: {{levat.result.players[0].account_id}}</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
(function() {
    var nesscafe = angular.module("steamPowered", []);

    var MainController = function($scope, $http) {
        var apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var matchID = prompt("Enter match ID: ")
        var returnedObject = function(response) {
            $scope.levat = response.data;
        }
        var onError = function() {
            $scope.errx = "ERROR: https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=" + matchID + "&key=" + apikey;
        }            $http.get("https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=" + matchID + "&key=" + apikey)
        .then(returnedObject, onError);
    }
    nesscafe.controller("MainController", MainController);
 }());
```

Comment: Helo @ FairPlay. If you are starting to learn angular now, I recommend that you use angular 2. Another problem that you can have is to use your api key directly in the javascript, so I know you can not leave it public. Are you using any language like php on the server? So you can keep your chage in your php code and make calls to it.

Comment: is it displaying the error message

Comment: not a wise thing to openly display your api keys......

Comment: Hey guys, I don't really care about API key, it's from a test account with CS:GO on it, I have multiple accounts so I really don't care about it, I will implement it in the backend if I ever really decide to make something more, main focus is on why GET isn't returning an object from the webserver as it's supposed to. @sachila ranawaka Yes it displays the ERROR message from the second parameter in the ".then()" method.

Comment: @dreadnought I forgot to say, I'm using older version of Angular as I'm currently following PluralSight tutorial on the subject, and the latest version isn't fully compatible with those videos, I'll just transition to version 2 after I get a good grasp on it.

Comment: @FairPlay this might be result of CORS. open the browser console check if there is a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error

Comment: Could you paste the error? I tried this on Postman and it works great!. The url I used was - `https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=%201000193456&key=08796B8615A61C4960F2054A0D67DB4E`  (I used your key as you don't care ;) ) Also noticed that the response didn't have a `data` attribute.

Comment: @sachila ranawaka, yep that's the error that's being show in the console, how do I fix that ?

Comment: you need to add CORS headers in server side

Comment: Thanks everyone, I know what to do now.